# Why isn't my footer being displayed in the document?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am putting together a website for a friend of mine who is a hair dresser and she wants a quick, flat-rate type of website so I decided bootstrap would be the avenue I take for the job.

I put together the navigation and the carousel just fine, but when I tried adding a card it placed the card almost in the direct middle of the carousel. I actually liked this look but was still confused as to how it happened and then I tried adding a footer to the landing page and now the footer doesn't show up, when I test the website for mobile devices the footer shows up along with a ton of unwanted white space.

**I included the carousel to show this is how my file is structured and to help see if this will bring a solution**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="imgs/hair_stylist.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="imgs/hair_dryer-2.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="imgs/hair_dryer.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card text-white text-center bg-dark mb-3" id="aboutSection">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Insert Welcome Message</h5>
    <p class="card-text">
      This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
    </p>
    <p class="card-text">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 2/22/2021</small>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
      © 2020 Copyright:
      <a class="text-dark" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a
              >
            </div>
            <!-- Copyright -->
          </footer>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your carousel and footer were both inside 'row', which was not required. I think that is the reason for overlap and white space.

You should only use class="row" if you want to divide a section into a bunch of columns as it applies css flex. Also use it inside a container/col as it also applies negative margin of 15px.

You also need jquery and bootstrap.js for the carousel navigation to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/deo8gq6t/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="card text-white text-center bg-dark mb-3" id="aboutSection">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Insert Welcome Message</h5>
    <p class="card-text">
      This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
    </p>
    <p class="card-text">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 2/22/2021</small>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <footer class="bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
      © 2020 Copyright:
      <a class="text-dark" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Copyright -->
  </footer>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove `mb-3` class from this `aboutSection` and add `col-md-12` class add in footer for full width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="imgs/hair_stylist.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="imgs/hair_dryer-2.webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="imgs/hair_dryer.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card text-white text-center bg-dark " id="aboutSection">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Insert Welcome Message</h5>
    <p class="card-text">
      This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
    </p>
    <p class="card-text">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 2/22/2021</small>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <footer class="col-md-12 bg-light text-center text-lg-start">
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
      © 2020 Copyright:
      <a class="text-dark" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">MDBootstrap.com</a
              >
            </div>
            <!-- Copyright -->
          </footer>
        </div>
```